# Как правильно сделать имплементацию LiveData

Tags: android

Есть у меня репозиторий в котором есть вот такой метод

```
@NotNull
public LiveData<String> getUserStatus()
{
    Flowable<String> status = getMainScreenDbObj().map(MainScreenDbObj::getUserStatus)//
                                                  .map(i -> mRes.getString(R.string.matmid_class, i))//
                                                  .toFlowable();

    return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(status);
}
```

Обращаемся в DB, конвертируем в `LiveData` и во `View` подписываемся на нее.

Проблема вот в чем, каждый раз когда я подписываюсь на `LiveData` и делаю всю эту итеракцию то результат прилетает мне во вью после того как оно уже открыто и получается что я не вижу ничего на экране и вдруг появляется текст...

Как это сделать с поведением `MutableLiveData` или `BehaviorSubject`, чтоб результат как то сохранялся и не летело обращение каждый раз в DB , а сразу возвращался результат?

Comment: а подписываетесь на LiveData в активити или во фрагменте?

Comment: во фрагменте в `onResume()`

Comment: если это делать во фрагменте, то всегда нужно подписываться, попробуйте вынести инициализацию в активити

Comment: Да но вопрос не в инициализации, а как нужно изменить имплементацию, чтоб она обращалась в дб только в том случае если раннее не было обращения. Если было то вернуть полученое значение